# RGBStroke - Image pixels instead of color (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, image-masking

I am implementing a image mask kind of feature in iOS similar to what is offered in the Blender app with two images. Here is my touch move code :-

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:staticBG1];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    [image_1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 20.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    image_1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
    mouseMoved++;
    if (mouseMoved == 10)
        mouseMoved = 0;
}
```

[image: The above code is generating an effect like :]

Now what I really want is **not the bright red line but pixels from another image** in those places. Both images are of the same dimensions. How do I do it?? 
I tried to implement my manual image processing method my pixel access but it was too slow and this will be done in real time.

Is there any alternative to:
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't draw a colour or a pattern into the path, draw transparency. You need one image in its own layer behind the image that is being wiped out. Create the path as you are now, but instead of setting the colour, set the blend mode to clear (`kCGBlendModeClear`).

This will remove sections of the image to allow you to see through to the image below.

---

Replace:

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

with:

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit. I tested with CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect, [staticBG2.image CGImage]); instead of the RGB color value but this draws the other image multiple times inside the base image.

Comment: The clear mode should be set after drawing the image and before stroking the path. The idea is that the path is cleared to transparent so you remove the image that was previously drawn into the context (instead of adding colour on top).

Comment: I was kind of drawing the whole back image many times in the path and then blending it... my bad.